# I cant find what causes the Exception

Tags: java, file, csv

I am a java noob as well as very new to this site so please bear with me here. If I do something wrong in posting this please let me know and I apologize in advance for anything I do happen to do or any bad grammar.

I need to write a custom CSV parser in java that does not separate commas inside quotations. I cannot use anything related to the CSV class.
1,2,3,4    ->   1  2  3  4
a,"b,c",d  ->   a  b,c  d

No matter what i try i always get an exception

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class csv
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File file = new File("csv.test");
        BufferedReader buf = null;

        try
        {
            buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            String str;

            while ((str = buf.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] values = null; // array for saving each split substr
                int c1 = 0; // counter for current position in string
                int c2 = 0; // counter for next space in array to save substr
                int c3 = 0; // location of last comma or quotation for substring creation
                int i = 0; // counter used later for printing

                while (c1 <= str.length())
                {
                    char x = str.charAt(c1);
                    String s = Character.toString(x);

                    if (c1 == str.length())
                    {
                        values[c2] = str.substring(c3, (c1 - 1));
                    }
                    else if (s == ",")
                    {
                        values[c2] = str.substring(c3, (c1 - 1));
                        c1++;
                        c2++;
                        c3++;
                    }
                    else if (s == "\"")
                    {
                        c1++;
                        c3 = c1;
                        while (s != "\"")
                            c1++;
                        values[c2] = str.substring(c3, (c1 - 1));
                        c1 = c1 + 2;
                        c2++;
                        c3 = c1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        c1++;
                    }
                    while (i < values.length)
                        System.out.println("\"" + values[i] + "\"");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error locating test file");
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried cutting out all logic and testing if it is file io related. that reads fine so im down to it being logic related. I looked it over and cannot find anything wrong with it. I even had a friend look it through and said it looked fine. Where is the exception thrown?

Comment: can you please include the full stacktrace? that would be a good start...

Comment: Can you share the related stacktrace?

Comment: Add `e.printStackTrace();` to the `catch` block and tell us what it says...

Comment: +1 for good conduct being a noob

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at csv.main( csv.java:56 )

Comment: And which line is "csv.java:56" ?

Answer (score 3):

You are not initializing your `values` in this line `String[] values = null;` hence it will fail when you use it i.e. at list `values[c2] = str.substring(c3, (c1 - 1));`.

To resolve the issue, please initialize the `values` array with proper length e.g. `String[] values = new String[SIZE];`. Probably you need to use `str.length()` as `SIZE` of the array.

Also in your comparison `else if (s == ",")`, you are comparing String using `==`, which is incorrect. Instead, you can use `x` itself as `else if (x == ',')`.

**Edit:** Your condition below will make `c1` in increment indefinitely as you are not changing the value of `str(x after correction as advised)` anywhere.

Old condition:

```
             while (s != "\"")
                  c1++;
```

After change as advised(still wrong as x is not changing within the while loop):

```
             while (x != '"')
                  c1++;
```

**Please correct the loop logic.**

Comment: i get an OutOfBounds exception on line 46 when i fix this. why is that?

Comment: @user1834642: I believe your line 46 is this: `values[c2] = str.substring(c3, (c1 - 1));` If so, your counters i.e. `c2, c3 & c1` are going beyond the string length. Please check the logic.

Comment: @user1834642: What are you expecting in the line `while (s != "\"")
                            c1++;`. This will cause your c1++ to increment indefinitely as you are not changing the value of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Not related to the concrete problem but instead of `s == ","`, you should do `",".equals(s)`, similar for other string equality checks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the cause of your exception, but it is obviously incorrect nonetheless:

```
    while (s != "\"")
        c1++;
```

It is incorrect for two reasons:

- Since the `c1++` doesn't alter the loop condition, this will loop for ever.
- You are using `==` / `!=` to compare strings when you should be using `equals(...)`.  You appear to have made this mistake in other places too.

---

To find out what is causing the exception, the first thing you should do is to print out the stacktrace.  Add `e.printStackTrace();` to the catch block.

Or better still, change it to just catch `IOException`.  Catching `Exception` is a bad idea ... unless you are going to log / output the full stacktrace.

Comment: what is the equivalent of != if == is s.equals().

Comment: @user1834642 - `! s.equals()`